# Conditional call of a FastAPI Model

Tags: python, mongodb, fastapi, pydantic

I have a multilang FastAPI connected to MongoDB. My document in MongoDB is duplicated in the two languages available and structured this way (simplified example):

```json
{
  "_id": xxxxxxx,
  "en": { 
          "title": "Drinking Water Composition",
          "description": "Drinking water composition expressed in... with pesticides.",
          "category": "Water", 
          "tags": ["water","pesticides"] 
         },
  "fr": { 
          "title": "Composition de l'eau de boisson",
          "description": "Composition de l'eau de boisson exprimée en... présence de pesticides....",
          "category": "Eau", 
          "tags": ["eau","pesticides"] 
         },  
}
```

I therefore implemented two models `DatasetFR` and `DatasetEN`, each one makeS references with specific external Models (`Enum`) for `category` and `tags` in each lang.

```py
class DatasetFR(BaseModel):
    title:str
    description: str
    category: CategoryFR
    tags: Optional[List[TagsFR]]

# same for DatasetEN chnaging the lang tag to EN
```

In the routes definition I forced the language parameter to declare the corresponding Model and get the corresponding validation.

```py
@router.post("?lang=fr", response_description="Add a dataset")
async def create_dataset(request:Request, dataset: DatasetFR = Body(...), lang:str="fr"):
    ...
    return JSONResponse(status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, content=created_dataset)

@router.post("?lang=en", response_description="Add a dataset")
async def create_dataset(request:Request, dataset: DatasetEN = Body(...), lang:str="en"):
    ...
    return JSONResponse(status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, content=created_dataset)
```

But this seems to be in contradiction with the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). So, I wonder here if someone knows an elegant solution to: - given the parameter lang, **dynamically call the corresponding model**.

Or, if we can create a Parent Model Dataset that takes the lang argument and retrieve the child model Dataset.

> This would incredibly ease building my API routes and the call of my models and mathematically divide by two the writing...

Comment: What's the rational behind the two models in the first place?

Comment: Can't you have a single Dataset class and define an extra field for the language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Option 1

A solution would be the following: Define `lang` as [`Query`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params/) paramter and [add a regular expression](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/#add-regular-expressions) that the parameter should match. In your case, that would be `^(fr|en)$`, meaning that only `fr` or `en` would be valid inputs. Thus, if no match was found, the request would stop there and the client would receive a *"string does not match regex..."* error.

Next, define the `body` parameter as a [generic type](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/python-types/#generic-types-with-type-parameters) of `dict` and declare it as [`Body`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-multiple-params/#singular-values-in-body) field; thus, instructing FastAPI to expect a `JSON` body.

Following, create a dictionary of your `models` that you can use to look up for a model using the `lang` attribute. Once you find the corresponding `model`, `try` to parse the `JSON` body using `models[lang].parse_obj(body)` (equivalent to using `models[lang](**body)`).  If no `ValidationError` is raised, you know the resulting `model` instance is valid. Otherwise, return an `HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY` error, including the errors, which you can [handle as desired](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#error-handling).

If you would also like `FR` and `EN` being valid `lang` values, adjust the regex to ignore case using `^(?i)(fr|en)$` instead, and make sure to convert `lang` to lower case when looking up for a model (i.e., `models[lang.lower()].parse_obj(body)`).

```
import  pydantic 
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response, status, Body, Query
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder

models = {"fr": DatasetFR, "en": DatasetEN}

@router.post("/", response_description="Add a dataset")
async def create_dataset(body: dict = Body(...), lang: str = Query(..., regex="^(fr|en)$")):
    try:
        model = models[lang].parse_obj(body)
    except pydantic.ValidationError as e:
        return Response(content=e.json(), status_code=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY, media_type="application/json")

    return JSONResponse(content=jsonable_encoder(dict(model)), status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

##### Update

Since the two models have identical attributes (i.e., `title` and `description`), you could define a parent model (e.g., `Dataset`) with those two attributes, and have `DatasetFR` and `DatasetEN` models inherit those.

```
class Dataset(BaseModel):
    title:str
    description: str
    
class DatasetFR(Dataset):
    category: CategoryFR
    tags: Optional[List[TagsFR]]
    
class DatasetEN(Dataset):
    category: CategoryEN
    tags: Optional[List[TagsEN]]
```

Additionally, it might be a better approach to move the logic from inside the route to a [dependency](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/) function and have it return the `model`, if it passes the validation; otherwise, raise an [`HTTPException`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/uk/tutorial/handling-errors/#raise-an-httpexception-in-your-code), as also demonstrated by [@tiangolo](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/471#issuecomment-584215664). You can use [`jsonable_encoder`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/encoder/), which is [internally used by FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-directly/), to encode the validation `errors()` (the same function can also be used when returning the `JSONResponse`).

```
from fastapi.exceptions import HTTPException
from fastapi import Depends

models = {"fr": DatasetFR, "en": DatasetEN}

async def checker(body: dict = Body(...), lang: str = Query(..., regex="^(fr|en)$")):
    try:
        model = models[lang].parse_obj(body)
    except pydantic.ValidationError as e:
        raise HTTPException(detail=jsonable_encoder(e.errors()), status_code=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)

    return model
        
@router.post("/", response_description="Add a dataset")
async def create_dataset(model: Dataset = Depends(checker)):    
    return JSONResponse(content=jsonable_encoder(dict(model)), status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

### Option 2

A further approach would be to have a single Pydantic model (let's say `Dataset`) and customise the [validators](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/) for `category` and `tags` fields. You can also define `lang` as part of `Dataset`, thus, no need to have it as query parameter. You can use a `set`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43634746), to keep the values of each `Enum` class, so that you can efficiently check if a value exists in the `Enum`; and have dictionaries to quickly look up for a `set` using the `lang` attribute. In the case of `tags`, to verify that every element in the list is valid, use [`set.issubset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset), as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16579295). If an attribute is not valid, you can `raise ValueError`, as shown in the [documentation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/), *"which will be caught and used to populate `ValidationError`"* (see "Note" section [here](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#error-handling)). Again, if you need the `lang` codes written in uppercase being valid inputs, adjust the `regex` pattern, as described earlier.

P.S. You don't even need to use `Enum` with this approach. Instead, populate each `set` below with the permitted values. For instance,
`categories_FR = {"Eau"}  categories_EN = {"Water"}  tags_FR = {"eau", "pesticides"}  tags_EN = {"water", "pesticides"}`. Additionally, if you would like not to use regex, but rather have a custom validation error for `lang` attribute as well, you could add it in the same `validator` decorator and perform validation similar (and previous) to the other two fields.

```
from pydantic import validator

categories_FR = set(item.value for item in CategoryFR) 
categories_EN = set(item.value for item in CategoryEN) 
tags_FR = set(item.value for item in TagsFR) 
tags_EN = set(item.value for item in TagsEN) 
cats = {"fr": categories_FR, "en": categories_EN}
tags = {"fr": tags_FR, "en": tags_EN}

def raise_error(values):
    raise ValueError(f'value is not a valid enumeration member; permitted: {values}')

class Dataset(BaseModel):
    lang: str = Body(..., regex="^(fr|en)$")
    title: str
    description: str
    category: str
    tags: List[str]

    @validator("category", "tags")
    def validate_atts(cls, v, values, field):
        lang = values.get('lang')
        if lang:
            if field.name == "category":
                if v not in cats[lang]: raise_error(cats[lang])
            elif field.name == "tags":
                if not set(v).issubset(tags[lang]): raise_error(tags[lang])
        return v

        
@router.post("/", response_description="Add a dataset")
async def create_dataset(model: Dataset): 
    return JSONResponse(content=jsonable_encoder(dict(model)), status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

###### Update

Note that in Pydantic V2, `@validator` has been deprecated and was replaced by `@field_validator`. Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71258131/17865804) for more details and examples.

### Option 3

Another approach would be to use [Discriminated Unions](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/unions/#discriminated-unions), as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71545639/17865804).

As per the documentation:

> When `Union` is used with multiple submodels, you sometimes know
> exactly which submodel needs to be checked and validated and want to
> enforce this. To do that you can set the same field - let's call it
> `my_discriminator` - in each of the submodels with a discriminated
> value, which is one (or many) `Literal` value(s). For your `Union`,
> you can set the discriminator in its value:
> `Field(discriminator='my_discriminator')`.
>
> Setting a discriminated union has many benefits:
>
> - validation is faster since it is only attempted against one model
> - only one explicit error is raised in case of failure
> - the generated JSON schema implements the associated OpenAPI    specification

Comment: I'm wondering if using a variable schema in a REST API is a good thing. In my opinion, that would be a new ressource "representation" thus the proposal of /lang/ prefix.

Comment: This is a very good proposal with  Body and Query regex and a dictionnary to map models. This is a good and easy to implement proposal. As I can't accept two proposals (can I?) I will choose the more canonical one with class factory and routes factory but I keep in mind yours. BTW I'm not sure of Update2 I want to explicitly set specific validators instead of Enum I have dozen of properties that needs to be validated. This would results to a long list of conditionnal that could not very readable...

Answer (score 4):

---

There are 2 parts to the answer (API call and data structure)

for the API call, you could separate them into 2 routes like `/api/v1/fr/...` and `/api/v1/en/...` (separating ressource representation!) and play with fastapi.APIRouter to declare the same route twice but changing for each route the validation schema by the one you want to use.

you could start by declaring a common BaseModel as an ABC as well as an ABCEnum.

```
from abc import ABC
from pydantic import BaseModel

class MyModelABC(ABC, BaseModel):
    attribute1: MyEnumABC

class MyModelFr(MyModelABC):
    attribute1: MyEnumFR

class MyModelEn(MyModelABC):
    attribute1: MyEnumEn
```

Then you can select the accurate Model for the routes through a class factory:

```
my_class_factory: dict[str, MyModelABC] = {
    "fr": MyModelFr,
    "en": MyModelEn, 
}
```

Finally you can create your routes through a route factory:

```
def generate_language_specific_router(language: str, ...) -> APIRouter:
    router = APIRouter(prefix=language)
    MySelectedModel: MyModelABC = my_class_factory[language]

    @router.post("/")
    def post_something(my_model_data: MySelectedModel):
        # My internal logic
    return router
```

---

About the second part (internal computation and data storage), internationalisation is often done through hashmaps.

The standard python library [gettext](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html) could be investigated

Otherwise, the original language can be explicitely used as the key/hash and then map translations to it (also including the original language if you want to have consistency in your calls).

It can look like:

```
dictionnary_of_babel = {
    "word1": {
        "en": "word1",
        "fr": "mot1",
    },
    "word2": {
        "en": "word2",
    },
    "Drinking Water Composition": {
        "en": "Drinking Water Composition",
        "fr": "Composition de l'eau de boisson",
    },
}

my_arbitrary_object = {
    "attribute1": "word1",
    "attribute2": "word2",
    "attribute3": "Drinking Water Composition",
}

my_translated_object = {}
for attribute, english_sentence in my_arbitrary_object.items():
    if "fr" in dictionnary_of_babel[english_sentence].keys():
        my_translated_object[attribute] = dictionnary_of_babel[english_sentence]["fr"]
    else:
        my_translated_object[attribute] = dictionnary_of_babel[english_sentence]["en"]  # ou sans "en"

expected_translated_object = {
    "attribute1": "mot1",
    "attribute2": "word2",
    "attribute3": "Composition de l'eau de boisson",
}

assert expected_translated_object == my_translated_object
```

***This code should run as is***

A proposal for mongoDB representation, if we don't want to have a separate table for translations, could be a `data structure` such as:

```
# normal:
my_attribute: "sentence"

# internationalized
my_attribute_internationalized: {
    sentence: {
        original_lang: "sentence"
        lang1: "sentence_lang1",
        lang2: "sentence_lang2",
    }
}
```

A simple tactic to generalize string translation is to define an anonymous function `_()` that embeds the translation like:

```
CURRENT_MODULE_LANG = "fr"

def _(original_string: str) -> str:
    """Switch from original_string to translation"""
    return dictionnary_of_babel[original_string][CURRENT_MODULE_LANG]
```

Then call it everywhere a translation is needed:

```
>>> print(_("word 1"))
"mot 1"
```

You can find a reference to this practice in the django documentation about [internationalization-in-python-code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-python-code).

For static translation (for example a website or a documentation), you can use .po files and editors like poedit (See the [french translation of python docs](https://github.com/python/python-docs-fr/blob/3.10/CONTRIBUTING.rst) for a practical usecase)!