# Interdependent Validation for Pydantic Model Fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

I have a model for a FastAPI request and I want to add some validation for its fields.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List, Optional

class RequestModel(BaseModel):
    types: List[str]
    segments: Optional[List[str]] = []
```

For the above snippet I want to ensure that `segments` list should only contain values if the length of the `types` list is `1`.

So, if the `segments` list has elements and length of `types` list is greater than `1` then it should return a validation error message to user.

How can this be done using Pydantic?

Comment: Have you seen the article in pydantics documentation about root validators? https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/#root-validators

Comment: @Chris I think you misunderstood the question. I don't see what value ranges have to do with this. Root validators would be a valid solution here.

Comment: @Chris Fair enough. Although the documentation has a whole page on validators that explains this in a much more general way with multiple examples. I would assume OP has read that and is none the wiser, so I doubt a specific answer to a different problem would help. Certainly this question is not a duplicate.

Comment: Related posts can also be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71258131/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71228281/17865804) (see Update 2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this?

```py
from typing import Any

from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError, root_validator


class RequestModel(BaseModel):
    types: list[str]
    segments: list[str] = []

    @root_validator
    def my_validator(cls, values: dict[str, Any]) -> dict[str, Any]:
        if len(values.get("types", [])) > 1 and values["segments"]:
            raise ValueError("Your error message here")
        return values


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(RequestModel(types=["foo"], segments=["a"]))
    print(RequestModel(types=["bar"]))
    print(RequestModel(types=[], segments=["b", "c"]))
    try:
        RequestModel(types=["spam", "eggs"], segments=["x"])
    except ValidationError as e:
        print(e)
```

Output:

```
types=['foo'] segments=['a']
types=['bar'] segments=[]
types=[] segments=['b', 'c']
1 validation error for RequestModel
__root__
  Your error message here (type=value_error)
```

---

An alternative is to use a normal `@validator` on the `segments` field and utilize the optional `values` parameter there. (see [docs](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/))
This is how that could look:

```py
from typing import Any

from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError, validator


class RequestModel(BaseModel):
    types: list[str]
    segments: list[str] = []

    @validator("segments")
    def my_validator(cls, v: list[str], values: dict[str, Any]) -> list[str]:
        if len(values.get("types", [])) > 1 and v:
            raise ValueError("Your error message here")
        return v


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(RequestModel(types=["foo"], segments=["a"]))
    print(RequestModel(types=["bar"]))
    print(RequestModel(types=[], segments=["b", "c"]))
    try:
        RequestModel(types=["spam", "eggs"], segments=["x"])
    except ValidationError as e:
        print(e)
```

Output is equivalent with a slightly different error structure.

Here the order of the fields matters because `values` will only contain those that were already validated and validation is done in the order that **fields are defined**. So you can not do this with a `@validator("types")` because by the time that validator is called, `values` will not contain an entry for `segments` yet.

---

**PS**: The reason I used `len(values.get("types", []))` instead of `len(values["types"])` in both cases is to ensure a properly formed error message. `types` is a required field and a validation error will therefore occur anyway, if the user tries to initialize an instance without providing a value for it. But Pydantic models will still go through the *entire* validation cycle anyway, and collect all occurrences of `ValueError`, `TypeError`, and `AssertionError`, before giving out a comprehensive error message about all of them.

If we simply tried to get `values["types"]`, but that key was not present in the dictionary because the user failed to provide it, this would trigger a `KeyError`, which is not properly processed as a `ValidationError` by Pydantic.